# Adding custom menu tab in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

In Drupal 7, it was possible with hook_navbar() but now in Drupal 8 I am not sure anymore how to do it. Do you have maybe some exampl?

Answer (score 0):

You need a local tasks menu link yml file, see example in node module
For this you need to create a route in the module.routing.yml file

```
route_name:
  path: 'admin/config/people/ban/settings'
  defaults: 
    _form: '\Drupal\modulename\Form\FormController'
    -title: Form Title
  requirements:
    _permission: 'your permission string'
```

then you need to create another yml file with the name mymodule.links.menu.yml

add the following code

```
form_config_link:
  title: Configure Form Title
  description: 'Configuration Form description'
  parent: system.admin_config_people
  route_name: route_name //defined above
```

You need to check system module yml file for parent name

Comment: Actually, I try to make a company logo in the Toolbar (upper black background) on the left side. What is the path for that and do I have to define menu link for that? In any case, thank you very much. This was very helpful.

Comment: try this http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-8/themes/upload-custom-logo